# Cell content disappears after set CellForItemAt indexPath size in CollectionViewFlowLayout?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm facing a weird problem. I'm using collectionViewFlowLayout sizeForItem to set cell size based on cell label width and somehow, I'm able to get the correct cell size but my content inside cell disappears. If I just put let say

```
CGSize(width: 30, height: frame.height)
```

I will see my label text. My collectionView scrollDirection is .horizontal

Below is my code:

```
let arrButtons = ["#B1","#ButtonButton2","#Bu3","#Buttontton11","#Buttodasfdsafasdn1","CongViecGiaDinh", "TinCongGiao"]

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let myText = arrButtons[indexPath.item]
    let font = UIFont(name: HelveticaNeueFont.HelveticaNeueRegular.rawValue, size: 16)
    return CGSize(width: myText.widthOfString(usingFont: font!), height: frame.height)
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.data = arrButtons[indexPath.item]
    cell.titleLabel.text = arrButtons[indexPath.item]
}


extension String {
    func widthOfString(usingFont font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
       let fontAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font]
       let size = self.size(withAttributes: fontAttributes)
       return size.width
    }
}
```

//extension is used to calculate label width

Comment: You named your function "heightOfString", but it's the width you want.. ;-). At any rate, what is the output of heightOfString in the debugger?  Also, what happens if you attach the fontAttributes to cell.titleLabel?

Comment: Well I should have renamed my func to widthOfString. Anyway, I still get correct width for the cell but the content inside the cell is gone.

Comment: @matt do you want to read 200+ line of code in a simple question? Anyway, thank for commenting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I used frame.height instead of collectionView.frame.height. Problem solved!